# How do I enable three finger gestures on my trackpad in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchpad

I have three finger gestures on and I have the sensitivity set to the highest level. It seems that every other time I turn on my computer (from wake/sleep), the three finger gestures stop working. How do I make it work always?

[image: 3-finger gestures]

[image: most sensitive]

I tried turning the touchpad off and on, but that didn't help.

This is not a duplicate of [Windows 10 3 finger touchpad swipe gestures don't work after wakeup](https://superuser.com/questions/958284/windows-10-3-finger-touchpad-swipe-gestures-dont-work-after-wakeup) because I am not using a Synaptic touchpad. I can't even find my touchpad in the Device Manager. It shows I have 2 mice instead.

Samsung Model NP940X5N.

[image: windows version]